# Issue in sending email

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7.3

I am working on an example that is for sending an email using `Swift`. I am using the following code:

```
@IBAction func sendMailButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["abc@gmail.com"])
            mail.setMessageBody("<p>You're so awesome!</p>", isHTML: true)
           // mail.addAttachmentData(<#T##attachment: NSData##NSData#>, mimeType: <#T##String#>, fileName: <#T##String#>)
            presentViewController(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Error Received While sending mail")        }

    }
```

When I click the send button of the MFMailComposeViewController() to send the mail, I receive the error in the device logs as:

```
>     1. <Error>: 18:32:54.282 [0x16e1bb000] >vibe> Error: Empty atoms array
>     2. ERROR:    [0x16e1bb000] 919: Vibe engine could not play vibe pattern, err = -50, actionID = 1001. Please file a bug.
```

Comment: can you please post whole log?

Comment: @AnjaliBhimani thats the only device logs that i get. The MFMailComposeResult rawValue is 2.

Comment: Are you testing on device or simulator?

Comment: @crisisGriega testing on iPhone 6s device.

Comment: Sorry @PrabhakarPatil but I can't help, all the attempts I can't reproduce the error. Sure it has something to be with the mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the server firewall of the organisation. It is blocking the server port to send the mail. Tried to send the mail using cellular network and it worked.